# Response/callback for JSONP using jQuery $.ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am unable to catch response from C# to jQuery using `$.ajax`.  I get an error `"SCRIPT ERROR"`. How can I catch response using JSONP? This is what i am using:

```
$.ajax({
    async: true,
    context: mrq,
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: MYURL,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: MYDATA,
    processData: false,
    jsonp: "jsonREQ",
    jsonpCallback: "onJSONPsuccess",
    success: function (jsonText, textStatus) {}
});
```

Comment: What error do you get exactly?

Comment: my error - "Global Error Handler called.  Msg is:Script error."

Comment: so could you please post the full script (the server response) or the URI to it?

Comment: @Bergi the server response in a serialized json.but ajax success is not catching it.

Comment: Does it have its padding? Please post it.

Comment: @Bergi this is my response -- {"msg":"value recieved using JSON-P is = test"}

Comment: You can't use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) without padding? Do you at least know how it works?

Comment: ya i know but i am unable to use padding in response.eg- callback({'data':'data'}).how can this be used for response.?

Comment: You can only use JSONP if the server provides that API. If it doesn't, you will have to adjust the API - if you don't own the service, you have no chance.

Comment: how can this be resolved any idea/advice??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, `dataType: 'jsonp'` means that as soon as it's returned it's put into the callback function as an argument. So, I'd try this:

```
onJSONPsuccess = function(response) {
  // do something with response, e.g.
  results = response["results"]
}

$.ajax({
  crossDomain: true,
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  data: { /*params you're sending in*/ },
  jsonp: "jsonREQ",
  jsonpCallback: "onJSONPsuccess",
  success: onJSONPsuccess
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You say the server side is C# - are you using WCF? There's a great article here about it:
http://bendewey.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/using-jsonp-with-wcf-and-jquery/

Basically you need to set up WCF (or whatever server-side code you're using) to return the json wrapped in a call to your callback function.

However, with jquery, you can simply add "?Callback=?" to your URL, change the dataType to 'jsonp', and forget about the rest of that stuff. You don't need the jsonp or jsonpCallback options set.

In contrast to a json request, the jsonp request will return your data *not* wrapped in a 'd' property, so your call back function is:

```
function(data) { var a = data.myProperty ... }
```

rather than

```
function(data) { var a = data.d.myProperty ... }
```

and the whole method is along the lines of:

```
var url = configuration.serviceUrl + "/" + method + "?callback=?";

var options = {
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    data: args,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
        if (callback != null) callback(data);
    }
};

if (typeof errorCallback != 'undefined')
    options.error = errorCallback;

$.ajax(options);
```